# passing value to a website for authentication

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to create a flask app that can pass user inputted values (username and password) to a form on a website. Is there a way to do this, specifically within the flask app, i'd like to be able to pass values from the app to another web server/page. The webpage is a form and I'm passing values to get authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

So if I get you right, you basically want to preform a HTTP POST-method to the specified URL the form you want to submit data to has set as its **action** property.

What you in this case need is the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-post-request) module.